# Ember's titleBinding on a link-to helper breaks Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm currently upgrading out Ember application to Ember 1.3.0 stable. I'm encountering the following issue in our Jasmine tests:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object])
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.Ember.Error (http://localhost:8888/assets/rake-ember.js?body=true:837:23)
    at Object.Ember.assert (http://localhost:8888/assets/rake-ember.js?body=true:79:13)
    at Object.Ember.MANDATORY_SETTER_FUNCTION [as keywords] (http://localhost:8888/assets/rake-ember.js?body=true:3446:13)
    at withHelper (http://localhost:8888/assets/rake-ember.js?body=true:27796:40)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/assets/rake-handlebars.js?body=true:1500:23), <anonymous>:88:28)
    at Handlebars.VM.template (http://localhost:8888/assets/rake-handlebars.js?body=true:2214:33)
    at renderPartial (http://localhost:8888/assets/rake-ember.js?body=true:29502:7)
    at partialHelper (http://localhost:8888/assets/rake-ember.js?body=true:29479:9)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/assets/rake-handlebars.js?body=true:1500:23), <anonymous>:54:99)
```

It seems that this is happening on the following bit of code:

`{{#link-to 'someroute' somemodel titleBinding="view.someproperty"}} Hi! {{/linkTo}}`

We've narrowed it down to the `titleBinding` property above, when removing it - our tests can then continue to run. Anyone have any insight here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use new Binding syntax `title=somepropery`

Comment: or title.view.somepropery